# 3G Not Working on Nexus One

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc, nexus-one, mobile-data

I used **cm-7.2.0-passion(stable)** on my Nexus One since Jan-2013 without any problems. A few days ago, I have installed **ev_passion-4.0.0p4.2-perdo-squished** from evervolv.com. Today again i installed **cm-7.2.0-passion(stable)** on my device.

But now i noticed that i can't access internet using 3G connection. I set APN settings manually as on my service provider's website. Even though 3G was on, there were no 3G icon appearing in the top bar.

Before installing roms, I did a **wipe data/factory**, **wipe cache** and **format** **system** using ClockworkMod Recovery.

My baseband version is `32.41.00.32U_5.08.00.04`

How can i solve this ?